# Accessing Childpage Control Value from Master Page Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page with a button and i have a client page with master page reference. I would like to change the child page label values while i click the master page button. I can't change that.

```
 Label StrHref= (Label)MainContent.FindControl("lblhead");
 HiddenField StrCalId = (HiddenField)MainContent.FindControl("hf_callid");

 StrHref.Text = "12345678901";
 StrCalId.Value = "1395741766.47";
```

Comment: Object reference not set to be an instance of object

Comment: can you post aspx of your child page

Comment: I think the id you given is wrong, and its not finding the lable or hidden field

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code on your masterPage button click event.

I have kept one button on masterpage with name as *btnMaster* and on child page I have put on text box and on click of MasterPage *btnMaster* I have used the below method.

```
protected void btnMaster_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = this.ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtChild") as TextBox;
        textbox.Text = "Text from Master to child control";
    }
```

Let me know if you have any issue.